# Angular 2 Input binding vs string change detection

Tags: javascript, angular

Let's say I have the following component:

```
class TestComponent {
  @Input() title;
}
```

Is there a difference regarding change detection between using it with brackets and without brackets?

```
<test [title]="title"></test>
<test [title]="'Component Title'"></test>  
<test title="Component Title"></test>
```

To be more accurate, the static version, will be checked with every change detection, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you declared `@Input` Angular will create bindings for all of them.
It will add it to `updateDirectives` function that is called during change detection cycle.

So the following

```
<test [title]="title"></test>
<test [title]="'Title2'"></test>
<test title="Title3"></test>
```

will be presented as:

```
updateDirective(_ck, v) {
  var _co = _v.component;
  var currVal_1 = _co.title;
  _ck(_v,4,0,currVal_1);
  var currVal_2 = 'Title2';
  _ck(_v,7,0,currVal_2);
  var currVal_3 = 'Title3';
  _ck(_v,10,0,currVal_3);
}
```

**[Live Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/8AN3ZtNejGWbYNAULiQN)**

[image]

The main difference here is that angular read `@Input` binding and also create attribute for `title="Title3"`case. If you don't declare `@Input` then only attribute will be created.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation - have deleted my incorrect answer. I hadn't realised that `@Input` did implicit property binding like this - do you happen to have a reference to the docs that explains this (And perhaps the logic behind it?)

Comment: So even if it is a string, it will check it in every change detection? Title3 === Title3 or Title2 === Title2?

Comment: @match There is one logic for all `@Input`. Angular doesn't distinguish whether it's static property or not. It just use the same code for all inputs.

Comment: @undefined Yeah, right. At least it's in current version of angular